# How to integrate postgREST with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgrest

I am fairly new to Django and looking for an API to access postres DB in Django. I tried to find the solution for integrating **postgREST** in my Django project, but couldn't find any solution. I would like to have some direction on how to integrate postgREST in Django, or if i can use some other API.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check out http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ it will help you.

Comment: You could put nginx in front of both your django app and your postgrest server. Have nginx route certain requests to postgrest, for instance maybe paths beginning with `/api`. Or run postgrest on a subdomain like `api.myapp.com`.